# Can JOptionPane options do something after being clicked?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane I've been working with this morning as I'm trying to learn Swing! I've been looking at the reference pages by oracle, and the farthest I got was to make 2 buttons that when you click either of them, they close (so they do the same thing.) Is there a way I can check when a button is clicked and do something (like printing something?)

My code works, I just need help on what to do next.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane frame = new JOptionPane();
      //Custom button text
        
        Object[] options = {"Barack",
                            "Obama"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
            "His name is..",
            "Obamas name is?",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,     //do not use a custom Icon
            options,  //the titles of buttons
            options[0]); //default button title
    }
  }
```

Output when running:

[image: the frame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a JOptionPane button has been pressed by using things like YES_OPTION and NO_OPTION.

```
if(n == OptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //do this
}
```

This works the same for NO_OPTION and also OK_OPTION. Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! I realized this but never got to change the question to have the answer! For anyone looking on how to do this, do what this guy said!

Comment: ah that's interesting, I've only ever used it with one option so I hadn't noticed it